# Loopback: Relation Through - not working

Tags: mongodb, api, foreign-keys, relational-database, loopback

So, I am stuck on an issue, that should be simple, and I am sure I am missing something obvious

I am following this documentation:

so I have 3 tables

client, team, client-team

client.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "teams": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "team",
      "foreignKey": "teamId",
      "through": "client-team"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

team.json

```
{
  "name": "team",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "default": "first-team"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "clients": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "client",
      "foreignKey": "clientId",
      "through": "client-team"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

client-team.json

```
{
  "name": "client-team",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "clientId": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "teamId": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "client": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Client",
      "foreignKey": "clientId"
    },
    "team": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Team",
      "foreignKey": "teamId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

so all the relations set correctly (I think)...

then in my clients I do have 1 client

```
[
  {
    "name": "Client name",
    "id": "59876185508eb519385779c6"
  }
]
```

and in my teams I have many, but for sure this:

```
[
  {
    "type": "type",
    "name": "Team name",
    "id": "5ae8a37add2989a32d37f83d"
  }
]
```

And then I go to my

> localhost:3000/explorer

To POST a client-team

like this

```
{
    "clientId": "59876185508eb519385779c6",
    "teamId": "5ae8a37add2989a32d37f83d"
}
```

and I get the 200 response with:

```
{
  "clientId": "59876185508eb519385779c6",
  "teamId": "5ae8a37add2989a32d37f83d",
  "id": "5ae961873a7e3b33f0579fc3"
}
```

so the connection is there....

But then, when I go to "GET client/id" and do

> id: 59876185508eb519385779c6
>   filter: {"include":["teams"]}

this is the response

```
{
  "name": "Chelsea FC",
  "id": "59876185508eb519385779c6",
  "teams": []
}
```

The same happens in the "GET teams/id" and I use

> id: 5ae8a37add2989a32d37f83d
>   filter: {"include":["clients"]}

or if I go to "GET teams/{id}/clients"
and put
id: 5ae8a37add2989a32d37f83d

I get

```
[]
```

So what am I doing wrong? I am sure I am missing a stupid, obvious thing :/

using mongo if that makes any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three issues here:

1. You described mongodb identifiers as string, that's why you store strings in database instead of object ids. (it's not required as the datasource should understand the real type)
2. Your models start from lower case letter. The same should be in the relations also. (the first part of the problem, it's fixing issue with ids)
3. Incorrect relations for client and team models (the second part of the problem, it's fixing includes)

client-team.json

```
{
  "name": "client-team",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "clientId": {
      "type": "objectId", // !!! changed (not required)
      "required": true
    },
    "teamId": {
      "type": "objectId", // !!! changed (not required)
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "client": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "client",  // !!! changed
      "foreignKey": "clientId"
    },
    "team": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "team",  // !!! changed
      "foreignKey": "teamId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

client.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "teams": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "team",
      "foreignKey": "clientId", // !!! changed (we describing id of this model, not team)
      "through": "client-team"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

team.json

```
{
  "name": "team",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "default": "first-team"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "clients": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "client",
      "foreignKey": "teamId", // !!! changed (the same as the previous)
      "through": "client-team"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Comment: @DS_web_developer let me check

Comment: @DS_web_developer re-check my comment

Comment: nope... still 0, it doesn't change things... the explorer still gives me the option to post as string... and if I do that... still get empty array

Comment: I just recreated this as a fresh project... and it works as expected... so I might have some error somewhere else. thanks for trying to help

Comment: Hm.... not so fast... I recreated it with db models and not mongo, where id's were numerical..... I tried to do it with mongo... and it is not working :/

Comment: this works... thanks! I knew I was making a silly mistake like that :/ You deserve a pint or two!